# Delete big amount of data and primary index

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, bigdata, clustered-index

I'm trying to delete big amount of rows (>10 million, it about 1/3 of all records in a table) from InnoDB MySQL table with primary/clustered index.
Field `id` is primary/clustered index and it's continuous without gaps. At least it should be, I do not delete records in a middle. But it's possible that some insert queries fails and innodb allocates some ids that became unused (I'm not sure if it is true). I delete only old records that no longer needed. Table contains varchar columns, so rows does not have fixed size.

First my attempt:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id<=10000000
```

It fails with big io operations. It seems to be that mysql killed this query and rolled back all changes. Approximate time for query execution was 6 hours and approximately same for rolling back.
My big mistake there is that transaction log size was standard 5mb, be aware of it. It have to be enlarged.

Second attempt to delete in chunks by 10 000 records, like:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id<=10000;
COMMIT;
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id<=20000;
COMMIT;
```

And so on. Query execution time from beginning was about 10 seconds (on laptop). Execution time grow gradually and it was about 300 seconds per query after 6 hours of execution.

Third attempt to make queries that in average executes less than 1 second. php code:

```
protected function deleteById($table, $id) {
    $MinId          = $this->getMinFromTable($table, 'id');
    $PackDeleteCount= $this->PackDeleteCount;
    $timerTotal     = new Timer();
    $delCountTotal  = 0;
    $delCountReport = 0;
    $delInfo        = array();
    $PackMinTime    = round($this->PackDeleteTime - $this->PackDeleteTime*$this->PackDeleteDiv, 3);
    $PackMaxTime    = round($this->PackDeleteTime + $this->PackDeleteTime*$this->PackDeleteDiv, 3);
    $this->LogString(sprintf('Del `%s`, PackMinTime: %s; PackMaxTime: %s', $table, $PackMinTime, $PackMaxTime));
    for (; $MinId < $id;) {
        $MinId          += $PackDeleteCount;
        $delCountReport += $PackDeleteCount;
        if ($MinId > $id) {
            $MinId = $id;
        }
        $timer          = new Timer();
        $sql            = sprintf('DELETE FROM `%s` WHERE id<=%s', $table, $MinId);
        $this->s->Query($sql, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        $delCount       = $this->s->AffectedRows();
        $this->s->CommitT();
        $RoundTime      = round($timer->end(), 3);
        $delInfo[]      = array(
            'time'  => $RoundTime,
            'rows'  => $PackDeleteCount,
        );
        $delCountTotal  += $delCount;
        if ($delCountReport >= $this->PackDeleteReport) {
            $delCountReport = 0;
            $delSqlCount    = count($delInfo);
            $EvTime         = 0;
            $PackTime       = 0;
            $EvCount        = 0;
            $PackCount      = 0;
            foreach ($delInfo as $v) {
                $PackTime   += $v['time'];
                $PackCount  += $v['rows'];
            }
            $EvTime         = round($PackTime/$delSqlCount, 2);
            $PackTime       = round($PackTime, 2);
            $EvCount        = round($PackCount/$delSqlCount);
            $TotalTime      = $this->readableTime(intval($timerTotal->end()));
            $this->LogString(sprintf('Del `%s`, Sql query count: %d; Time: %s; Count: %d; Evarage Time %s; Evarage count per delete: %d; Del total: %s; Del Total Time: %s; id <= %s', $table, $delSqlCount, $PackTime, $PackCount, $EvTime, $EvCount, $delCountTotal, $TotalTime, $MinId));
            $delInfo        = array();
        }

        $PackDeleteCountOld = $PackDeleteCount;
        if ($RoundTime < $PackMinTime) {
            $PackDeleteCount    = intval($PackDeleteCount + $PackDeleteCount*(1 - $RoundTime/$this->PackDeleteTime));
        } elseif ($RoundTime > $PackMaxTime) {
            $PackDeleteCount    = intval($PackDeleteCount - $PackDeleteCount*(1 - $this->PackDeleteTime/$RoundTime));
        }
        //$this->LogString(sprintf('Del `%s`, round time: %s; row count old: %d; row count new: %d', $table, $RoundTime, $PackDeleteCountOld, $PackDeleteCount));
    }
    $this->LogString(sprintf('Finished del `%s`: time: %s', $table, round($timerTotal->end(), 2)));
}
```

It has some dependencies, but they are self explanatory and can be easily changed with standard.
I'll explain only input variables that are used here:

```
$table - target table, where rows needs to be deleted
$id - all records up to this id should be deleted
$MinId - Minimal id in the target table
$this->PackDeleteCount - Initial count of records, to start from. Then it recalculates row count to be deleted each new query.
$this->PackDeleteTime - desirable query execution time in average. I used 0.5
$this->PackDeleteDiv - acceptable deviation from $this->PackDeleteTime. In percentage. I used 0.3
$this->PackDeleteReport - Each N records should print statistic information about deleting
```

This variant has stable performance.

The reason of weak performance is that database engine have to physically resort all record data in leaves that was affected. It is my understanding and if your knowledge is deeper you are welcome to add description of what actually is going on in details. Perhaps it will give some new ideas.

Question: Is it possible to calculate row distribution on leaves and delete whole leave or even branch, so database engine does not have to resort data?
Perhaps you have some other ideas on performance optimization for this case.

Comment: Perhaps try dropping the indexes before the delete, and redefining them again afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this a few times, usually I go along the lines of creating a partition (or several first) as this will reduce the IO required by INNODB for large delete queries without having to rebuild the entire index tree - then chunk delete between 1000 - 1500 at a time.

It's also practice to:

- Set AutoComit to 1
- Chunk the deletes into about 1,500 at a time
- Make sure innodb_log_file_size has a large enough size

Comment: - Is there difference between autocommit and "commit" query after each query?
 - chunks with fixed rows count are not optimal. I did a test. Optimal row count highly depend on hardware and current load on the server. In most cases on real server execution time of query will grow. So it's much better to calculate count of rows to delete based on query execution time to regulate load depending on current state of server.
 - innodb_log_file_size is now fine, it was my first mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000000
```

Comment: It should be lot slower than `id < 10000000`.